# Improving A Legacy ASP.NET WebForms Project to Modern Standards

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, webforms, cloud

I was given a project in WebForms to make robust and I had so far added several improvements to it. Don't get me wrong, I like WebForms for its simplicity but much of it is I feel like 'grandfather' type of coding.

Here's what I did, just to give you some ideas:

1.) Added VueJS to the frontend

2.) Added Webpack and a bit of ReactJS to on some pages

3.) Used .NET core on running a custom protocol app that triggers from inside the WebForms project

4.) I've added an emailing function (Inbox, Sent Items, Drafts, Trash, Junk, etc.) (from WebForms and jQuery, another one was WebForms + VueJS) to it as well.

It has gotten pretty big. I was just wondering if it will be scalable? Our management is thinking of putting it on the cloud soon but I believe it wouldn't work because of the architecture of our project - we will have to slowly transition it to modern web standards (apply MVC, use WebAPIs rather than WebMethods (static) on CodeBehind files).

I really am lost. What's the best route in improving a WebForms project to modern standards? Something scalable and cloudable (if that even is a word).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(Let me reach for my flame-retardant underwear.)

The big difference between WebForms and more contemporary web design frameworks is that WebForms attempts to layer an event-driven forms management paradigm on a platform that is not built for events.  Web pages are not desktops.

In my experience, the efforts to maintain the illusion of web events in a complex application far outweigh the investment in taking the original functional requirements to MVC, or NodeJS, or React, or some framework that is designed for the calls and responses of the stateless servers of the Web.

I vote do-over.  You will have to do your own cost/benefit analysis if you want to take that route.  If you do go that way, this forum is a good place to post specific questions with code samples related to coding problems that you uncover on your journey.